# how can i return view using ajax in laravel?

Tags: ajax, laravel, post, httprequest

i got some problem here, i would like to chek my data when i post it using ajax
here is my ajax

**ajax.js**

```
let dataNewMemoData = JSON.stringify(createnewMemoData);

 $.ajax({
url: '/crew_memo/submitdata',
method: 'POST',
dataType: 'json',
contentType: 'json',
data: dataNewMemoData,
headers: {'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')},
contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
})
```

and then here is my web route

**web.php**

```
 Route::post('/crew_memo/submitdata', 'CrewProgramController@saveData');
```

and here we are at my controller

**controller.php**

```
public function saveData(Request $request){

    $request = json_decode($request->getContent());
    return view('CrewProgram.succes')->render();
    // return dd($request);
}
```

first i want to go to my `succes.blade.php` i dont know why my page never go anywhere event tough my post method is alright

[image]

seconds, i want to look at my data so its posible to use `return dd($request)` how can i solve it?

i were tried to use this

`return (String) view(CrewProgram.succes)` 
and 
`return view(CrewProgram.success)->render()`, before

and nothings works so help me someone, im using laravel

Comment: after sending the post request are you catching the callback ? you should catch the call back and update the dom.

Comment: i'm sory, what do you mean a callback? i'm beginer

Comment: specify 'Accept': 'application/json','Content-Type': 'text/plain' in headers and check again.

Comment: after making the post request. it returns you that view codes. now in your javascript code you have to catch that in a success function and then you can update the dom html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to fix your AJAX data

from your version

```
$.ajax({
url: '/crew_memo/submitdata',
method: 'POST',
dataType: 'json',
contentType: 'json',
data: dataNewMemoData,
headers: {'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')},
contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
})
```

to this

```
$.ajax({
url: '/crew_memo/submitdata',
method: 'POST',
contentType: 'json',
data: { content : dataNewMemoData},
headers: {'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')},
success : function(data){
   console.log(data) //this will be your html respone make sure you don't have any html or header or body tag inside your view file you want to render.
},
error : function(jqXHR,textStatus,thrownError){
   console.log(jqXHR) //for non 2xx or 3xx response code
}

})
```

Now we'll go to your Controller method

from this
    public function saveData(Request $request){

```
    $request = json_decode($request->getContent());
    return view('CrewProgram.succes')->render();
    // return dd($request);
}
```

to this

```
public function saveData(Request $request){

        $request = json_decode($request->get('content));
        return view('CrewProgram.succes')->render();
        // return dd($request);
```

}

can  you create this `PageRequest.php` file to your `app\Http\Requests`  folder

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;

class PageRequest extends FormRequest
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            //
        ];
    }
}
```

then instead of

```
public function saveData(Request $request){}
```

you make it

```
public function saveData(PageRequest $request){}
```

then check the value of `$request->all()` by doing `dd($request->all())`

Comment: create the PageRequest.php file i've sent

Comment: seems  like your using the Request global class.

Comment: or if your comforable using this method in  ajax :  data: dataNewMemoData, that's okay  just remove those unnecessary key  in your ajax

Comment: i got error its says pageRequest isn't there https://imgur.com/yx6bEwV even tough i already add it  https://imgur.com/2u6rBIS

Comment: and why i shouldnt use global request class?

Comment: i modified your answer into ```dd($request->all())``` and i got null data in there when i try using only request i got this https://imgur.com/CIQbNq4

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way. update your controller like this.

```
       return response()->json([
            'htmlData' => view('CrewProgram.succes')->render()
        ]);
```

and set your jquery

```
 $.ajax({
    url: '/crew_memo/submitdata',
    method: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: 'json',
    data: dataNewMemoData,
    headers: {'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')},
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    success: function (data) {
       alert(data.htmlData)
     }
    })
```

Comment: i got the alert but, my page is not changing into CrewProgram.succes, and how can i check my data is there, you know i need to check how is my data already on the controller or not using dd()